# Using Node js request module for JSON from API, can't access subcategories

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, request

I have a weird issue where I can successfully obtain data from an API source using Node js and the request module, but when I try to access a certain subcategory of the JSON data, the object becomes undefined.

Here's my code:

```
var request = require("request")

var url = "http://api.8coupons.com/v1/getcategory"

request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
        console.log(body.headers['categoryID']) // creates an error
        console.log(body.categoryID) // creates an error
    }
})
```

Here's my terminal output when I run the program:

```
node getJS.js 
[ { categoryID: '1', category: 'Restaurants' },   
{categoryID: '2', category: 'Entertainment' },   
{ categoryID: '3', category: 'Beauty & Spa' },   
{ categoryID: '4', category: 'Services' },  
{ categoryID: '6', category: 'Shopping' },   
{ categoryID: '7', category: 'Travel' } ]

C:\path\to\code\getJS.js:12
    >         console.log(body.headers['categoryID'])
    >                                 ^
    > 
    > TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryID' of undefined
    >     at Request._callback (C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Bill-e\getJS.js:12:33)
    >     at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Bill-e\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
    >     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    >     at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
    >     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Bill-e\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
    >     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    >     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    >     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Bill-e\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
    >     at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    >     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a little mistake here.

Your json data in the first level is an array so, to access the data, you need to pass the index you want to get from the array (directly or inside an iteration)

```
console.log(body[0].categoryID);
```

or

```
body.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.categoryID);
})
```

The headers is a property of the response param, to get the response headers from request (data like content-type, cookies)

Comment: That was it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is way you are reading response. In your case `body` is array. so you should read it like `body[index].categoryID` and `body[index].category` Where `index` can be in between `0` to `5` as your response has `6` objects